# Hibernate can't delete updated object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities being managed by Hibernate.  Let's call them `User` and `UserRecord`.  A `User` contains a set of `UserRecord`s and each `UserRecord` contains one `Integer`.
Something along these lines:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userKey")
    @Index(name = "ByUserKey", columnNames = "userKey")
    private Set<UserRecord> userRecordSet;

    ...
}
```

-

```
@Entity(name = "UserRecord")
public class UserRecord implements Comparable<UserRecord>, Serializable
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name = "userRecordKey")
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer recordNumber;
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "userKey") @Index(name = "ByUserKey", columnNames = "userKey")
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

A Spring form on one page gives our users a set of fields to change the record numbers associated with their account.  Adding or changing numbers on this page works fine.  Deleting seems to be an issue here.

We have a function that attempts to remove any blank records from the list before the User is saved back to the database.

```
private void removeBlankUserRecords(User user)
{
    Set<userRecord> userRecordSet = user.getUserRecordSet();
    if (userRecordSet != null && !userRecordSet.isEmpty())
    {
        Iterator<UserRecord> iterator = userRecordSet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            UserRecord record = iterator.next();
            if (record.getRecordNumber() == null || record.getRecordNumber().equals(Integer.valueOf(0)))
            {
                if (record.getId() > 0) //If object already exists in the DB
                {
                    //Set the record number to a sentinel value to avoid null error
                    record.setRecordNumber(Integer.valueOf(-1));
                }
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I look at the database after the transaction has completed, I still have the deleted `UserRecord` in the database with the sentinel value.  Stranger still, if I go through the process again, deleting the sentinel value off in the Spring form, the delete then works.

It seems that as long as the `UserRecord` object has data being changed it can't be deleted.  Can somebody please explain to me why this is happening?